# Convert PIL.Image to/from Gtk.Picture/Gtk.Image in gtk4

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library, gtk4

I do RGBA image manipulation in PIL(low) and would like to display the resulting image in a gtk4 application. For that, I'd need a seamless `PIL.Image` <--> `Gtk.Picture`/`Gtk.Image` converter. I'd like to avoid using temporary files at all cost. I found helpful hints [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51154279/python-gtk3-image-from-pil-jpg-format) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7906814/converting-pil-image-to-gtk-pixbuf) but was wondering if there was anything more convenient in gtk4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of GTK 4.4, this seems to work best:

```
buffer = GLib.Bytes.new(pil_image.tobytes())
gdata = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_bytes(buffer, GdkPixbuf.Colorspace.RGB, True, 8, pil_image.width, pil_image.height, len(pil_image.getbands())*pil_image.width)
gtk_image = Gtk.Image.new_from_pixbuf(gdata)
```

Once GTK 4.6+ becomes ubiquitous, GdkPixbuf should be replaced with GdkTexture, via [Gdk.Texture.new_from_bytes()](https://docs.gtk.org/gdk4/ctor.Texture.new_from_bytes.html).